# Artifact black lines on raytraced mesh (with Embree)

Tags: c++, mesh, raytracing, artifacts, embree

I am developing a Embree based ray tracer (currently very early in development). If you are not familiar with Embree you can read more at their [webpage](https://embree.github.io/api.html).

The issue:
Currently if you start the renderer to use 1 ray per pixel and per iteration (referred to 1 ray mode from now on), it renderers just fine. If you set it trace 4 rays in a packet (`raypacket4`) it renders the mesh fine, util you move some distace away from it, then some black lines appear.

[Issue Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td0sq.jpg)
Screenshot camera parameters are (all in ray packet mode):

> 1. position 0, 1, 0, rotation 20, 0, 0
> 2. position 0, 38, 0 rotation 90, 0, 0
> 3. position 9.5, 5, 0 rotation 90, 0, 0
> 4. position 9.5, 38, 0 rotation 90, 0, 0

Investigation showed that the lines appear only in pakcet mode and when some distance away from mesh.
I am posting screens of the issue (rendered images) in several different camera positions.
Here is the source code of the project (on GitHub) [Source Code](https://github.com/AlexanderMladenov/EmbreeRT/tree/master/src)

My bet is that the problem is in either the packet generation (found at `camera.cpp/GetRayPacket4`) or in the rendering (`renderer.h/RenderBuffer4, Raytrace4`).
Switching between the modes is done in main.cpp by just replacing `RenderToBuffer4` with `RenderToBuffer` and `RTC_INTERSECT4` to `RTC_INTERSECT1`.

Any help or ideas are much appreciated.

Edit:

I apologize for the lack of config files, or scene files, it is currently in very early dev stage( 2 days spent) and everything is hardcoded for testing at the moment.

Edit 2:

I have discovered that removid the + i in the ray direction calculation in GetRayPacket4, removes the issue, but then the 4 packed rays are identical. Why would that fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

The issue was that the __m128 keeps the data in reverse order, so some pixel swapping had to take place.